# jQuery Hover Problems

Tags: jquery

I've got this problem with some jQuery. I want to display this div when you hover over an element and hide it when you aren't on it.

```
$(function() {
    $('#projects').hover(function() {
        $('#projects .pane').show(200), $('#projects .pane').hide(200);
    })
});
```

When you hover it disappears the same time.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Take a look at how I edited your post to make it more readable. That'll help you get a quicker and better answer to your question here at SO. (Code should be formatted as code. You don't need HTML breaks to format the text. etc.) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#projects').hover(function() {
        $('#projects .pane').show(200);
    }, function(){
        $('#projects .pane').hide(200);
   });
});
```

The [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) expects two function parameters. One for when mouse is over and other one when mouse is away.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the function(){ seperator, hence the current code is including hide and show in the mouse over event.
Try this:

```
$(function() {     
    $('#projects').hover(function(){         
        $('#projects .pane').show(200)
        }, function(){
         $('#projects .pane').hide(200);     
         });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#projects').hover(function() {
        $('#projects .pane').show(200)},

            function() {$('#projects .pane').hide(200);}
    )
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fCbQv/1/